# Tell me I'm pretty!

Tags: code-golf

I only very recently discovered code golf and just found this part of the Stackexchange network, and naturally after looking at so many clever answers, I feel inferior. Inner me knows I'll get better over time, but inner me is also vain and needs validation.

At the same time, I don't take kindly to pandering, so you'd **better** not write me a program that looks like it took 15 seconds. You have to *mean* it.

## Goal:

Print the phrase "you're pretty!" or write a function that returns that string. All letters can be upper-case or lower-case, but the punctuation and the spacing must be the same.

## How to mean it:

If you're sensitive and can sympathize with all the emotions associated with feeling like a noobie, you should aim to make your program look like it does something entirely different and innocuous. I like to be surprised :) You may achieve this by not using any of the alphabetical characters in "you're pretty".

Winner is decided by shortest byte count. -5 bytes for each positive or neutral adjective you extend the phrase by, i.e. "you're pretty and effulgent and green", up to a possible 20 byte reduction.

Comment: I feel like jelly can get a negative score on this one..

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I'm afraid to say that, as it stands, your challenge is quite vague. It should have objective winning criterion. If the challenge is just to output `you're pretty`, then it's a dupe of the Hello, World! question. If it's about adding adjectives, then what defines a neutral/positive adjective?

Comment: Since you're new here, you should really take a look at the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) before posting a challenge.

Comment: @briantist Oh ok, thanks, I will! Sorry, I was getting the impression that really all I had the power to do with my current rep was answer questions and post them, but I'll do that next time :)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien can you link me to this Hello, World! question?

Comment: You're pretty..

Comment: [Hello, World!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>29</s> 28 - 20 = <s>9</s> 8 points

```
“+vẇSȮv¿⁷“ñż“ÞỌ“Ḋ;“ʠK»j“ and
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYY522cNd7cEn1pUd2v@ocTtQ4PDGo3tA1LyHu3uA9MMdXdZA6tQC70O7s4AMhcS8lP//AQ)

The bonus turns out to be just *marginally* worth it for Jelly: `“+vẇSȮv¿⁷»` (the compressed representation of `you're pretty`) is 10 bytes. (Now with another byte saved per @ConorOBrien; I'd forgotten that as the final `and` is uncompressed, it wouldn't need a trailing delimeter.)

### Explanation

```
“+vẇSȮv¿⁷“ñż“ÞỌ“Ḋ;“ʠK»j“ and
“+vẇSȮv¿⁷“ñż“ÞỌ“Ḋ;“ʠK»        ["you're pretty"," airy"," agile"," calm"," brave"]
                      j       join with
                       “ and  " and"
```

This is pretty much just a case of using Jelly's built-in string compression. Picking adjectives that come near the start of the alphabet makes it slightly shorter than it would be otherwise.

Incidentally, this program would be quite a bit shorter if Jelly's dictionary were more complete. It has plenty of obscure words in, but for some reason is missing `and` (likely because it's only three letters long and thus doesn't gain much from the compression, but it'd benefit from being included in the dictionary for when it's used as part of a longer string, because `“¡ÞṄɱ»` is longer than just writing out the word would be).

Comment: You can leave off the trailing quote: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYY522cNd7cEn1pUd2v@ocTtQ4PDGo3tA1LyHu3uA9MMdXdZA6tQC70O7s4AMhcS8lP//AQ "Jelly – TIO Nexus")

Comment: Jelly's dictionary contains all words from my distro's `/usr/share/dict/words` that are composed of two or more ASCII letters. For whatever reason, said dictionary contains **AND**, but not **and**...

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 bytes

```
`YŒ'œ pÎ5y
```

Japt uses the [shoco library](http://ed-von-schleck.github.io/shoco/) for string compresstion. Backticks are used to decompress strings.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@58QeahH/dAchYLDfaaV//8DAA)

Comment: Wow, the entire program is shorter than the string `"you're pretty!"`...

Comment: Not that it matters (since the question is closed), but this doesn't seem to be a valid answer: it uses 'Y', 'p', 'y', all of which are characters from the required phrase "You're pretty!"